# Can an object only have kinetic energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy

I can imagine scenarios where there is no kinetic energy, however I can't seem to find any situation where there is no potential energy.

Comment: Kinetic energy and/or potential energy are pieces of a model. Consider the model of a ball on top of a hill with no velocity wrt the ground has potential energy and no kinetic energy. Consider a simple model for a ball floating in empty space: it has only kinetic energy (in the sense that it suffices to fully describe its dynamics via the "action principle").

Comment: Both kinetic and potential energy are reference frame dependent. Therefore, you can always find some reference frame where kinetic energy and potential energy is not zero. You can also find some reference frame where kinetic and potential energy is zero.

Answer (score 1):

The work done by the total external force is the change in kinetic energy (KE).  Consider one external force. The change in potential energy (PE) is defined as the negative of the work done by that force if it is a conservative force, gravity for example. It can simplify the evaluation of the work done by such a force.  Therefore, the change in PE is another way of accounting for the work done by a conservative force.

Consider a ball on a horizontal surface given a quick kick; the force applied changes the KE but after the force is applied the KE is constant.  For such a force there is no PE defined so the ball has KE but no PE; the KE is the work done by the force that kicked the ball.

Answer (score 1):

Single photons are pure kinetic energy, based on:

$$ T = \sqrt{p^2+m^2} - m = E-m=\omega =k $$

(with $\hbar=c=1$).

I can't imagine a potential energy for a photon, and in a photon gas, the chemical potential is zero..so: photons.

Comment: Does gravitational potential energy count? If you take a coordinate system such that locally well-defined gravitational potential energy exists for anything, I would suggest that photons have it too (and exchange it for kinetic energy when they gravitationally blueshift).